# How to install cordova/phonegap plugins on PhoneGap Developer App

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-developer-app

I'm trying to add [this plugin](https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-with-compression) to a PhoneGap application.

I used this command:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-media-with-compression
```

And I can see the plugin correctly added in the list of plugins running this:

```
$ phonegap plugin list
```

But when I use the **PhoneGap Developer App** (on iPhone) the plugin is not available.

I'm running this code in order to get **the list of installed plugins** at runtime:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

  var pluginList = cordova.require("cordova/plugin_list").metadata;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(pluginList));

});
```

The above code returns two different sets of plugins if I run the application from a browser or from the PhoneGap Developer App. From **browser** I get this:

```
{
  "cordova-media-with-compression": "2.1.0",
  "cordova-plugin-battery-status": "1.1.2",
  "cordova-plugin-camera": "2.1.1",
  "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.1.0",
  "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.4",
  "cordova-plugin-contacts": "2.0.1",
  "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.3",
  "cordova-plugin-device-motion": "1.2.2",
  "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": "1.0.4",
  "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "1.2.1",
  "cordova-plugin-file": "4.3.0",
  "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.5.1",
  "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "2.1.0",
  "cordova-plugin-globalization": "1.0.4",
  "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "1.3.0",
  "cordova-plugin-network-information": "1.2.1",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "3.2.2",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.1.3",
  "cordova-plugin-vibration": "2.1.2",
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.2.2"
}
```

And from the **PhoneGap Developer App** I get this:

```
{
  "com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin": "5.3.0",
  "cordova-plugin-battery-status": "1.2.0",
  "cordova-plugin-ble-central": "1.1.2",
  "cordova-plugin-camera": "2.3.0",
  "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.0.0",
  "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.4",
  "cordova-plugin-contacts": "2.2.0",
  "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.3",
  "cordova-plugin-device-motion": "1.2.2",
  "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": "1.0.4",
  "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "1.3.0",
  "cordova-plugin-file": "4.3.0",
  "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.6.0",
  "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "2.4.1-dev",
  "cordova-plugin-globalization": "1.0.4",
  "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "1.5.0",
  "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "4.2.0",
  "cordova-plugin-media": "2.4.0",
  "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "1.4.0",
  "cordova-plugin-network-information": "1.3.0",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "4.0.0",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.0",
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.0",
  "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.1.3",
  "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "6.0.3",
  "phonegap-plugin-contentsync": "1.2.5",
  "phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility": "1.0.4",
  "phonegap-plugin-push": "1.8.3"
}
```

As you can see, in the first list there is the plugin `cordova-media-with-compression` while in the second list there is not.

Why the two list of plugins are not equals? How can I get new installed plugins also in the *PhoneGap Developer App*?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the *Phonegap Developer App* come with a set of plugins out of the box and it is not possible to add other external plugins: http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/troubleshoot-faq/

> If you're using a plugin in your project that is not shown in this list, it will not work with the PhoneGap Developer App out of the box.
>   However, you can create [your own custom build of the PhoneGap Developer app](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/custom-build/ios/) locally and include any other plugins there.

The *official* suggestion is to create a custom build of the Developer App.

These are some discussions on github about this issue:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/247
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/209